# Python - Ocr with Knn-Algorithm expand testdata

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I try to write a Ocr for numbers in Python using OpenCV and the Knn-Algorithm. The code works pretty well but i want to expand my input data to move on to handwritten digits. Training / input of data works like that: You run the script, where the path of a image is, then the image opens with a rectangle around the number and you have to press the number on the keyboard. At the end it saves the classifications and flattened images in a textfile.

The problem is that it overrides the old textfiles so this data gets lost.

Is it possible / does it work to append the new and the old textfile?

This is the code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 35

RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 20
RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 30

def main():
    imgTrainingNumbers = cv2.imread("training_chars.png")   

if imgTrainingNumbers is None:                          # if image was not read successfully
    print "error: image not read from file \n\n"        # print error message to std out
    os.system("pause")                                  # pause so user can see error message
    return                                              # and exit function (which exits program)
# end if

imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgTrainingNumbers, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)          # get grayscale image
imgBlurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray, (5,5), 0)                        # blur

                                                    # filter image from grayscale to black and white
imgThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred,                           # input image
                                  255,                                  # make pixels that pass the threshold full white
                                  cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,       # use gaussian rather than mean, seems to give better results
                                  cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,                # invert so foreground will be white, background will be black
                                  11,                                   # size of a pixel neighborhood used to calculate threshold value
                                  2)                                    # constant subtracted from the mean or weighted mean

cv2.imshow("imgThresh", imgThresh)      # show threshold image for reference

imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.copy()        # make a copy of the thresh image, this in necessary b/c findContours modifies the image

imgContours, npaContours, npaHierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgThreshCopy,        # input image, make sure to use a copy since the function will modify this image in the course of finding contours
                                             cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,                 # retrieve the outermost contours only
                                             cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)           # compress horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leave only their end points

                            # declare empty numpy array, we will use this to write to file later
                            # zero rows, enough cols to hold all image data
npaFlattenedImages =  np.empty((0, RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH * RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))

intClassifications = []         # declare empty classifications list, this will be our list of how we are classifying our chars from user input, we will write to file at the end

                                # possible chars we are interested in are digits 0 through 9, put these in list intValidChars
intValidChars = [ord('0'), ord('1'), ord('2'), ord('3'), ord('4'), ord('5'), ord('6'), ord('7'), ord('8'), ord('9'),
                 ord('-'), ord('o'), ord('c')]

for npaContour in npaContours:                          # for each contour
    if cv2.contourArea(npaContour) > MIN_CONTOUR_AREA:          # if contour is big enough to consider
        [intX, intY, intW, intH] = cv2.boundingRect(npaContour)         # get and break out bounding rect

                                            # draw rectangle around each contour as we ask user for input
        cv2.rectangle(imgTrainingNumbers,           # draw rectangle on original training image
                      (intX, intY),                 # upper left corner
                      (intX+intW,intY+intH),        # lower right corner
                      (0, 0, 255),                  # red
                      2)                            # thickness

        imgROI = imgThresh[intY:intY+intH, intX:intX+intW]                                  # crop char out of threshold image
        imgROIResized = cv2.resize(imgROI, (RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))     # resize image, this will be more consistent for recognition and storage

        cv2.imshow("imgROI", imgROI)                    # show cropped out char for reference
        cv2.imshow("imgROIResized", imgROIResized)      # show resized image for reference
        cv2.imshow("training_numbers.png", imgTrainingNumbers)      # show training numbers image, this will now have red rectangles drawn on it

        intChar = cv2.waitKey(0)                     # get key press

        if intChar == 27:                   # if esc key was pressed
            sys.exit()                      # exit program
        elif intChar in intValidChars:      # else if the char is in the list of chars we are looking for . . .

            intClassifications.append(intChar)                                                # append classification char to integer list of chars (we will convert to float later before writing to file)

            npaFlattenedImage = imgROIResized.reshape((1, RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH * RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))  # flatten image to 1d numpy array so we can write to file later
            npaFlattenedImages = np.append(npaFlattenedImages, npaFlattenedImage, 0)                    # add current flattened impage numpy array to list of flattened image numpy arrays
        # end if
    # end if
# end for

fltClassifications = np.array(intClassifications, np.float32)                   # convert classifications list of ints to numpy array of floats

npaClassifications = fltClassifications.reshape((fltClassifications.size, 1))   # flatten numpy array of floats to 1d so we can write to file later

print "\n\ntraining complete !!\n"

np.savetxt("classifications.txt", npaClassifications)           # write flattened images to file
np.savetxt("flattened_images.txt", npaFlattenedImages)          #

cv2.destroyAllWindows()             

return
```

Thank you

Comment: I guess you already thought of appending the new and old textfile into a file or database of some sort. So what's your challenge here?

Comment: I tried now this code:
with open("classifications.txt", "a") as myfile:
     np.savetxt(myfile, npaClassifications) 


    with open("flattened_images.txt", "a") as myfile:
  np.savetxt(myfile, npaFlattenedImages)

It seems to work but Im not completely sure whether the classifications and flattended images files work better than before.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it.

```
print "\n\ntraining complete !!\n"

if os.path.exists("classifications.txt") == False: 
    np.savetxt("classifications.txt", npaClassifications) 
    np.savetxt("flattened_images.txt", npaFlattenedImages) 


elif os.stat("classifications.txt").st_size == 0:  
    np.savetxt("classifications.txt", npaClassifications)  
    np.savetxt("flattened_images.txt", npaFlattenedImages)  #

else:  
    f = open("classifications.txt", 'ab')
    np.savetxt(f, npaClassifications)
    f.close()
    e = open("flattened_images.txt", 'ab')
    np.savetxt(e, npaFlattenedImages)
```